# New to Arrays (struggling)

Tags: java

I'm just learning about arrays. I have a small program to write that asks to create 2 arrays. One holding 5 names of flowers. One holding the prices of those 5 flowers. I ask the user what kind of flower they want and the quantity. I then need to create a loop that locates the flower name and uses that index to find the cost of the flower. I am struggling on how to write in code how to use one array index to find another. Example: Roses and $.50. I know I'm basically asking for a lot here but i just  have no clue how to call from one array to another. Any help would be amazing. Thank you. here is what i have so far.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] flowers = new String[] {"petunias", "pansy", "rose", "violet", "carnation"};
    double [] cost = new double[] {.50, .75, 1.50, .50, .80};
    for(int pq = 1; pq <= 5; pq++){
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the flower purchased: ");
```

Comment: You're overcomplicating. Take it one step at a time. First, find the index in the `flowers` array of the user's input. Then, return the item in the `cost` array at that index.

Answer (score 1):

Like henry said above  just loop through the flower array and finds its index. This index will be the same correspondingly to its cost in the cost array. When there's a match print the element at that index in cost array.

```
        String [] flowers = new String[] {"petunias", "pansy", "rose", "violet", "carnation"};
        double [] cost = new double[] {.50, .75, 1.50, .50, .80};

        System.out.print("Enter the name of the flower purchased: ");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in))
        String input = br.readLine();

        for(int i=0;i<flower.length;i++){
            if(input.equals(flowers[i])) {
                system.out.print(cost[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Given that this is pretty clearly a homework, a little explanation might be more helpful than just code.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
String [] flowers = new String[] {"petunias", "pansy", "rose", "violet", "carnation"};
double [] cost = new double[] {.50, .75, 1.50, .50, .80};
System.out.print("Enter the name of flower purchased: ");
String key = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
for (int i = 0; i < flower.length(); i++){
String flw = flowers[i].getName();
if ( flw.startswith(key)){ // you don't have to use startswith(key) 
    // you should be able to do the rest.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i undetstood, flower names are stored in one array and their prices are stored in another array at the same index.

```
import java.util.*;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] flowers = new String[] {"petunias", "pansy", "rose", "violet", "carnation"};
    double [] cost = new double[] {.50, .75, 1.50, .50, .80};
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the flower purchased: ");
    String temp= keyboard.nextLine();
    for(int pq = 0; pq <= flowers.length; pq++){
    if (temp==flowers[i]) //compare your input with the array of flowers
    System.out.print(flowers[i]+" costs "+cost[i]; // display name and corresponding price
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick walkthrough on what I used to get this working.

```
    String [] flowers = new String[] {"petunias", "pansy", "rose", "violet", "carnation"}; //flower array
    double [] cost = new double[] {.50, .75, 1.50, .50, .80}; //cost array

    System.out.print("Enter the name of the flower purchased: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //new scanner to read user input
    String input = in.nextLine(); //gets the line from the user

    for(int i=0;i<flowers.length;i++){ //loop through the flower array, checking if the flower's name matches the user input
        if(input.equals(flowers[i])) { //if we have a match...
            System.out.print(cost[i]); //output the price
        }
    }
```

So basically the flowers array and prices array are one-to-one meaning you can draw a clear line between any one flower and its corresponding price. Since this relation exists, it is possible to use the same index when iterating through the arrays. e.g: pansy -> .75

Say we are at `i = 1` in the loop...

if we input "pansy" for the type we are looking for, we will have `input.equals(flowers[i])` which is really `"pansy".equals("pansy")` which is true. then we will jump into the code `System.out.print(cost[i]);` which is saying at this point: `System.out.print(.75);` since i is 1.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work, I have this.

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double total = 0;
    String flowerName = "start";
    int quantity = 0;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Salisbury Flower Boutique");
    String [] flowerNameArray = new String[] {"petunias", "pansy", "rose", "violet",                     "carnation"};
    double [] flowerCostArray = new double[] {.50, .75, 1.50, .50, .80};
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the flower purchased : ");
    flowerName = keyboard.next();
    while (! flowerName.equals("done"));{
        System.out.print("Enter the quantity: ");
        quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    for(int index = 0; index <5; index++){
        if(flowerNameArray[index].equals(flowerName));
        total = total + (flowerCostArray[index] * quantity);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the flower purchased: ");
    flowerName = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("Total cost of the flower sale: $" + total);
}
```

}

but it won't work unless I type done first. (I need to have that in there so the user can enter it to exit the program).